# Получение слов из текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Помогите, пожалуйста! Нужно регулярное выражение, которое из текста (с символами, кириллицей) получает все слова (разделённые пробелами между друг другом) и пробивает их длинн.

Comment: Я суммировал длину всех слов, как выяснилось - я не увидел что у ТСа написано именно пробивало длину (как это - я не понимаю, вместо этого я прочитал прибавляло, возможно это опечатка, но не суть).

Кстати - может мне кто-то пояснить как это "пробить длину слова"?О_о

Comment: Опечатался так сказать) Длинна символов в слове)

Comment: 'пробивает их длинн', в переводе на русский - прибавляет их длину?
Если да - то исключительно регулярного выражения для этого недостаточно

Comment: @GeneralProger У всех символов в слове одинаковая длина: 1, 2 или 4 байта в зависимости от кодировки.

Answer (score 3):

Для того чтоб из текста состоящего из слов, разделенных толькол пробелами - не нужно использовать регулярные выражение. достаточно использовать функцию [array explode ( string separator, string string [, int limit] )](http://www.php.su/functions/?explode)

ПО ссылке вы найдете и пример ее использования.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'пыщь пыщь пыщь лол лол ололо';
foreach(explode(' ', $str) as $value) {
  $arr[] = array(
    'word' => $value, 
    'length' => strlen($value)
  );
}
print_r($arr);
// результат
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [word] => пыщь
            [length] => 8
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [word] => пыщь
            [length] => 8
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [word] => пыщь
            [length] => 8
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [word] => лол
            [length] => 6
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [word] => лол
            [length] => 6
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [word] => ололо
            [length] => 10
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Запиши эти слова в файл (например, words.txt или slova.txt) и прочитай его с помощью функции fgetcsv().

```
<?php
$x=fopen("slova.txt","r");
$y=fgetcsv($x,filesize($x),' ');
foreach($y as $line)
{
    echo $line;
};    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если уж так хотите регулярку:

```
$words = preg_split('/[\s\.,\!\?\:\-\(\)\;]+/', $str)
```